# Scala simple dummy project

Tags: scala, project-management, scala-2.8, sbt

Currently my whole work cycle is:

1. edit foo.scala
2. fsc foo.scala && scala -cp . FooMain

But my project is getting bigger and I would like to split files, make unit tests, etc.
But I'm too lazy for reading sbt documentation and doing whatever needs to be done to get a sbt's "Makefile". Similarly for unit tests (there are so many frameworks, which to choose?)

What would make my day is a simple zipped dummy project with a dummy unit tests using sbt.

Do you know whether such thing exists?

Comment: Just added another template for Scala project, this time based only on Maven.

Comment: I don't understand: the first part of my answer do advocate the use of sbt, except it comes with a *template* sbt project already ready to go, complete with test. What was wrong with that? Plus, for completion sake, I added several maven template projects as well.

Comment: Your answer and project is very good.
But my need are met just by using SBT according to manual, nothing more is needed as SBT will create project and test for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you *should* use SBT. You don't need to write anything for it: it will create everything you need for a basic project, and only ask you what is the project name and what version of Scala you'll be using.

After that, just put the files in the correct places. Look up the directory layout, though the short answer is main source files in `src/main/scala` and test source files in `src/test/scala`. You *will* have to create a very small "makefile" to get a test library in, though.

Answer (score 9):

Updated answer (2016)

These days, you have the [**Giter8**](http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/) project, combined with the sbt’s launcher version 0.13.13 or above, [and its command **`new`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40561242/6309).

```
sbt new ...
```

---

Original answer (2010)

Yes, such a template project, based on sbt, complete with scala tests, exists:

see [Get Started With Scala, Sbt And Eclipse](http://www.mgutz.com/2010/03/06/get_started_with_scala_sbt_and_eclipse.html) and its [template project](http://github.com/mgutz/sbt-console-template).

- 1) Clone OR download/extract source from sbt-console-template

```
    % git clone git://github.com/mgutz/sbt-console-template.git  your-project
```

- 2) From sbt console

```
       # update dependencies
       > update

       # run project
       > run

       # test project continuously
       > ~test

       # eclipsify
       > eclipse
```

(the "eclipse" part is optional, and only here if you want to generate a Scala eclipse project from your sbt project)

---

Another Scala template project:

**[Build a mixed Scala 2.8/Java application from scratch with Maven](http://mackaz.de/111)**

It uses the following template (here is the [zip file with the full Maven-Scala project](http://mackaz.de/wp-content/uploads/tutorial1.zip)):

```
+-scalajavatut/
  +-pom.xml
  +-src/
  | +-main/
  | | +-java/
  | | | +-de/
  | | |   +-mackaz/
  | | |     +-HelloScala.java
  | | +-scala/
  | |   +-de/
  | |     +-mackaz/
  | |       +-App.scala
  | +-test/
  |   +-scala/
  |     +-de/
  |       +-mackaz/
  |         +-AppTest.scala
  |         +-MySpec.scala
```

And the following `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.mackaz</groupId>
  <artifactId>tutorial1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <inceptionYear>2008</inceptionYear>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <scala.version>2.8.0-SNAPSHOT</scala.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- Scala 2.8 Latest -->
   <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org.snapshots</id>
      <name>Scala Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots</url>
      <snapshots />
   </repository>

  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Specs (Behavior Driven Testing through JUnit) -->
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.scala-tools.testing</groupId>
     <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
     <version>1.6.1-2.8.0.Beta1-RC1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <goals><goal>compile</goal></goals>
            <phase>compile</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <goals><goal>testCompile</goal></goals>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals><goal>compile</goal></goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
          <launchers>
            <launcher>
              <id>myLauncher</id>
              <mainClass>de.mackaz.App</mainClass>
            </launcher>
          </launchers>
          <args>
            <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg>
            <!-- to support mix java/scala only -->
            <arg>-make:transitivenocp</arg>
            <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
            <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
          </args>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <buildcommands>
            <buildcommand>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
          </buildcommands>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
          <classpathContainers>
            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
            <classpathContainer>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
          </classpathContainers>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

You can run it with:

```
mvn scala:run
```

> and at the end of the output you should see

```
[INFO] launcher 'myLauncher' selected => de.mackaz.App
Hello from Java
Scala says: Hello from Scala!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 24 18:14:22 CET 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/33M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

In [Fanf's blog](http://fanf42.blogspot.com/), [Francois Armand](http://www.blogger.com/profile/10948445494945956846) presents:

[Maven2 bootstrap pom.xml for Scala with SLF4J and no-commons-logging](http://fanf42.blogspot.com/2010/05/maven2-bootstrap-pomxml-for-scala-with.html)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>org.test</groupId>
 <artifactId>test</artifactId>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <properties>
  <!-- UTF-8 for everyone -->
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

  <!-- Other general properties -->
  <slf4j-version>1.6.0</slf4j-version>
  <logback-version>0.9.20</logback-version>
  <scala-version>2.8.0.RC2</scala-version>
  <scala-maven-plugin-version>2.13.1</scala-maven-plugin-version>
  </properties>

 <description>
  Starting pom
 </description>

 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>scala-tools.org</id>
   <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
   <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>scala-snapshots.org</id>
   <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository snapshots</name>
   <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots</url>
  </repository>

  <repository>
   <id>no-commons-logging</id>
   <name>No-commons-logging Maven Repository</name>
   <layout>default</layout>
   <url>http://no-commons-logging.zapto.org/mvn2</url>
   <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
  </repository>

 </repositories>

 <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>scala-tools.org</id>
   <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
   <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
   <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
  </pluginRepository>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>scala-snapshots.org</id>
   <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository snapshots</name>
   <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots</url>
  </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>

 <build>
  <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
  <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${scala-maven-plugin-version}</version> 
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <goals>
       <goal>compile</goal>
       <goal>testCompile</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
     <args>
      <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg>
      <arg>-make:transitivenocp</arg>
      <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
      <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
     </args>
     <jvmArgs>
      <jvmArg>-client</jvmArg>
      <jvmArg>-Xmx1G</jvmArg>
     </jvmArgs>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
    <source>1.6</source>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

  </plugins>
 </build>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
   <version>${scala-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
   <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
   <version>1.6</version>
  </dependency>
  <!--  test -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.7</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>


  <!--
   All the following is related to our will to NOT use Commong-logging
  -->
  <!-- use no-commons-logging -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
   <version>99.0-does-not-exist</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- no-commons-logging-api, if you need it -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
   <version>99.0-does-not-exist</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- the slf4j commons-logging replacement -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
   <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- the other slf4j jars -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- using slf4j native backend -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
   <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
   <version>${logback-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
   <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
   <version>${logback-version}</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it should be:
git://github.com/mgutz/sbt-console-template.git

Comment: @Łukasz: true. I have amended the answer to reflect the right git repo address.