# Create Simple Project SBT 0.10.X

Tags: scala, sbt

(This is a follow up to [sbt not creating projects correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6395070/244526). The question wasn't answered.)

---

Basically, [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6395070/244526) says "I don't know how to create a project under the new sbt. With the old one, I just ran `sbt` in a new folder and there was a guided wizard that led me through the setup."

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395070/sbt-not-creating-projects-correctly/6483881#6483881) does not explain how to create a new project, it just points to [the documentation](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Settings), which also doesn't explicitly say how to create a new project -- only how to write a `build.sbt` file.

So I tried first writing a `build.sbt` and then running `sbt` in the directory with the `build.sbt` file, but I still don't see a `src` directory to work with.

Could someone post a simple step-by-step (I'm assuming there are like 3 steps at most) guiding how to create a new project under sbt 0.10.X?

Comment: I think the latest changes to http://stackoverflow.com/q/6395070/1305344 made it a great source of different approaches to sbt project layout generation (and could make this question obsolete).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for at this webpage: [Scala 2.9.1, sbt 0.10 and ScalaTest step-by-step](http://www.paulbutcher.com/2011/09/scala-2-9-1-sbt-0-10-and-scalatest-step-by-step/).

The high-level steps are:

1. `mkdir my_project` make a folder for your project
2. Create a simple `my_project/build.sbt` file, e.g.:

   ```
   name := "A Project"

   version := "0.1"

   scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.6.1" % "test"
   )
   ```
3. Create a file `my_project/src/main/scala/HelloWorld.scala`, where you create all the directories you need as you go (e.g. create the directory structure `src/main/scala/`)

   `object Main extends App {
      Console.println("Hello World!")
    }`
4. Execute your sbt commands: e.g. `sbt run`

Comment: For a minimal solution the libraryDependencies can also be omitted. But is is nice to include them in the answer since one always needs some libs.

Answer (score 35):

I am surprised that noone gave another solution which is the closest to the old way (as mentioned by @dsg) to create a simple project in sbt:
Just run sbt in your project directory, then issue the following commands in the sbt REPL:

```
> set name := "MyProject"
> set version := "1.0"
> set scalaVersion := "2.9.0"
> session save
> exit
```

Granted, it is only mildly useful as it will just create the build.sbt file (enough to make it a proper sbt project) with the corresponding properties set, and you might as well create the file by hand (I usually prefer to do so myself). It won't create the `src` directory either.

Answer (score 16):

Just a few days ago **np** (*new project*) plugin to sbt was released. It intended to dealt exactly with that problem:

> Initial release. Provides a minimal interface for generating new sbt
>   projects via,... sbt.
>
> Basic use is to install the plugin globally and start up a new project
>   with

```
$ sbt 
$ np name:my-project org:com.mypackage version:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

> This will generate a simple *build.sbt* project for you along with the
>   standard project directory structure for main and test sources.
>
> For more advanced usage, see the project's [readme](https://github.com/softprops/np) for more info

Answer (score 11):

You can use https://github.com/n8han/giter8 to generate project layout using various templates

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of sbt, you can just install sbteclipse:

```
// ~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0")
```

then from sbt's console you can run:

```
eclipse with-source=true
```

In version 0.10.x I think this post can help you:

http://dcsobral.blogspot.fr/2011/06/very-quick-guide-to-project-creation-on.html

Answer (score 1):

I've been using https://github.com/ymasory/sbt-prototype skeleton. See also my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10556125/).

It was the first one that just worked and I've been a quite happy with it since then.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the recent sbt 0.13.3 **[`new` command](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/sbt-new-and-Templates.html)**:

Example:

> First, you need sbt’s launcher version 0.13.13 or above.
>   Normally the exact version for the sbt launcher does not matter because it will use the version specified by `sbt.version` in `project/build.properties`; however for new sbt’s launcher 0.13.13 or above is required as the command functions without a `project/build.properties` present.
>
> Next, run:

```
$ sbt new eed3si9n/hello.g8
....
name [hello]:
scala_version [2.11.8]:

Template applied in ./hello
```

> This ran the template [`eed3si9n/hello.g8`](https://github.com/eed3si9n/hello.g8) using **[`Giter8`](http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/)**, prompted for values for “name” and “scala_version” (which have defaults “`hello`” and “`2.11.8`”, which we accepted hitting [Enter]), and created a build under `./hello`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the GitHub repo [Scala SBT Template](https://github.com/dph01/scala-sbt-template). In particular the [buildt.sbt](https://github.com/dph01/scala-sbt-template/blob/master/build.sbt) file.

Just clone the repo, go to that directory, then call the `sbt` command.

```
 $ git clone git://github.com/dph01/scala-sbt-template.git
 $ cd scala-sbt-template
 $ ./sbt
```

From inside of `sbt`, you can type `run` to execute provided code. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to generate the project structure using Intellij:

- Create the directory for the project and include there a basic sbt file. You just need to specify the project name.

  name := "porjectName"
- With Intellij import the project. During the process check the options "Use auto-import" and "Create directories for empty content roots automatically"

That will create for you the basic skeleton for the sbt project.