# How create sbt template for projects?

Tags: scala, maven, build, sbt

I have an sbt build with 2 duplicated projects configuration. See example:

```
lazy val MyProjectOne = Project(id = "OneId", base = file("path/OneId"))
    .dependsOn(moduleOne)
    .settings(plugin.settings: _*)
    .settings(defaultSettings: _*)
    .settings(webSettings: _*)
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++= commonTests)

lazy val MyProjectTwo = Project(id = "TwoId", base = file("path/TwoId"))
    .dependsOn(moduleOne)
    .settings(plugin.settings: _*)
    .settings(defaultSettings: _*)
    .settings(webSettings: _*)
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++= commonTests)
```

It is obvious that `MyProjectOne` and `MyProjectTwo` differs only in `id` and `base` properties.
Is there a way to refactor sbt build like this:

```
lazy val template = Project()
    .dependsOn(moduleOne)
    .settings(plugin.settings: _*)
    .settings(defaultSettings: _*)
    .settings(webSettings: _*)
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++= commonTests)

//Just as example:
lazy val MyProjectOne = Project(id = "OneId", base = file("path/OneId")).extends(template)
lazy val MyProjectTwo = Project(id = "TwoId", base = file("path/TwoId")).extends(template)
```

How can I do that with sbt?

**Also**

With maven I can define a parent project pom for that case. Is there analog in sbt?

Comment: Since you write Scala, you can define a function for this.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/40561242/6309